# Apply css based on most recent ancestor?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Using css, I want to apply different styles to the element with the class `test`. But the style should be different, if it is inside an element with class `a` or class `b`:

```
<div class="a">
  lorem
  <div class="b">
    ipsum
    <div class="test">&nbsp;</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Should get a different style then

```
<div class="b">
  lorem
  <div class="a">
    imsum
    <div class="test">&nbsp;</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But if I apply the style

```
.a .test { background-color: red; }
.b .test { background-color: blue; }
```

both will have blue background: https://jsfiddle.net/emk5fozg/4/

I want the second one to be red, because it is a more direct child of `.a` than `.b`.

The problem is, I can not use the child selector `>`, because there may be some 7 or so layers of divs in between the relevant ones. (I counted, please don't ask why so many.)

How can I assign styles to elements based on most recent ancestor?

To clarify: I only want to style the .test divs, nothing around them. There are lots of other elements before and after them that should not get a style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```css
.a .test, .b .a .test{ background-color: red; }
.b .test, .a .b .test { background-color: blue; }
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <div class="b">
    <div class="test">&nbsp;</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="b">
  <div class="a">
    <div class="test">&nbsp;</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think im gonna use something like this.

Answer (score 3):

you could do it like that, just add one more selector

https://jsfiddle.net/emk5fozg/2/

```
.a .b .test {
  background-color: blue;
}

.b .a .test {
  background-color: red; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

They are the same. Is just like if you write first

```
    .test {
        background-color:red;
          }
```

and then change it to blue.You will have red color just if you write like this

```
    .b .test { background-color: blue; }
    .a .test { background-color: red; }
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is too specify the entire filiation:

```
.b .a .test { background-color: red; }
.a .b .test { background-color: blue; }
```

and even more precise by specifying the direct parents:

```
.b > .a > .test { background-color: red; }
.a > .b > .test { background-color: blue; }
```